# Spring Loggers implementation

Tags: spring, logging

I am using Loggers in my Spring Web Application. But when I am enabling the logger at Debug/Info level, the logs inside the Spring Jars are also getting Printed in the Log file. Pls tell me how to stop internal Logs from getting displayed.

**My Logger Implementation :**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class);
```

**Log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file


log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File="location"
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

***These are the Unwanted Logs and Many more like this ..***

```
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  DispatcherServlet:444 - FrameworkServlet 'SpringApp': initialization started
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:495 - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringApp-servlet': startup date [Thu Mar 05 20:16:02 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:315 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringApp-servlet.xml]
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner:202 - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner:210 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:139 - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:557 - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a5e65f: defining beans [loadController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/logout],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.logout(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.loginUI()
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/loginAction],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.loginClicked(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/loadLop],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.loadLop()
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/loadOthers],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.loadOthers()
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/jobStatus],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.getJobStatus(javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.errorHandling()
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/LOPAction],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.LOPAction(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/PartsAction],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.partsAction(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/LoadOthersAction],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.loadOthersAction(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  RequestMappingHandlerMapping:190 - Mapped "{[/LoadOthersAction2],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.nagesh.testLoad.Controller.LoadController.loadOthersAction2(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
2015-03-05 20:16:02 INFO  Version:17 - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.0.Alpha1
2015-03-05 20:16:03 INFO  DispatcherServlet:463 - FrameworkServlet 'SpringApp': initialization completed in 1399 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the spring logging level to error or warn based on your need like below.

log4j.logger.org.springframework=ERROR

Answer (score 0):

You can use SLF4J as facade if you make out with multiple loggers(log4j, springs commons-logging, javautil's logging). For more details [slf4j explanation](http://java.dzone.com/articles/use-slf4j-logging-spring)